# Simulink function, Comparing two signals, how to remove startup spike?

Tags: matlab, function, simulink

I have a function where i am comparing two signals but i am getting a spike at the beginning, how do i fix this ?  the spike is at time one, later the output seems correct.

Code is:

```
function InBalance = Balance(String1SOC, String2SOC)
%#codegen
if (String1SOC >= (String2SOC-0.01) && String1SOC <= (String2SOC+0.01))
    InBalance = 1;
else
    InBalance = 0;
end
```

Comment: You need to give us enough information to reproduce the problem, otherwise it's impossible to say. What do the input signals look like? Have you tried it in MATLAB before implementing in Simulink?

Comment: without posting a picture no.  i get a starting spike at 1 even though the StringSOC arent within range.  What i mean by spike is a signal of 1 for 1 tick before zero and then 1 when it is supposed to.

Comment: the signal is a SOC from the Battery lithium model at mathworks with a Transferfunction inbetween because of algebraic loop problems

Comment: If you post a link to the picture, somebody with enough reputation can edit the question and insert it for you. Regardless, there is not enough information provided. Have you tried your algorithm with the signals in MATLAB before implementing in Simulink? If it doesn't work in MATLAB, there's something wrong with the algorithm itself. Otherwise, it's to do with the Simulink implementation, in which case we would need to see the model & settings (solver, time step, etc...)